# Is there a carousel for Angular 4+?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need to create a carousel of different information (words only). 
I looked all over internet. Majority of carousels are for images and written in JS/Jquery. 
Is there one for Angular?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-carousel-in-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.html)

Comment: I have been looking for something like this as well.

Comment: So what type of carousel you are looking for? can you just give any example link even of js or jquery plugin?

Answer (score -1):

yes there are multiple npm packages for `angular`. You can try `ngx-gallery` and also `ngx-slider`. Checkout their implementation on `npm`

Comment: I think they wanted a slider where you don't show images.